# How to see replies to your comments on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, account-management, comments

When I accidentally opened the notification window two times the replies there disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check replies to your comments, just got to the YouTube channel that posted the video, find your comment, and open replies. If you saw replies before and they are no longer there than its possible that the people who replied deleted their comments (reply to your comment). You can also try a different browser which sometimes can fix problems like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can see your own comments by clicking on History in the left menu, then Comments in the right menu. Then you can open each comment in a new tab and look at them and their replies.

Note that if your comment was a reply to a top-level comment it will always appear to be the last one in the thread, so you will have to click the "3 replies" link to see if there were any replies after your comment.

You may want to check your YouTube settings for Notifications to see if notifications for replies to your comments are turned off, as this is the easiest way to see them.

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem. From what I’ve read, this often happens if YouTube detects the comment to be spam. Basically the comments are automatically deleted, but it doesn’t remove the “reply”.

Comment: This is a different problem, and it's also not an answer to the question.